# Rails and Devise when I already have a Session domain model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

During implementing Devise into an existing Rails project I'm running into an issue with out app already having a Session model that relates to our application and not a user's web session. I've tried several work arounds and the only thing that really works is to rename our model, but this isn't really acceptable due to a number of internal reasons.

```
    #routes snippet

    devise_for :web_users, controllers: {
      sessions: 'web_users/sessions'
    }

    root 'pages#index'

    authenticate :web_user do
      resources :sessions, only: [:index, :show]
    end
```

This was the furthest along I got by overriding the controller with:

```
    class WebUsers::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
      before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

      # GET /resource/sign_in
      def new
        super
      end

      # POST /resource/sign_in
      def create
        super
      end

      # DELETE /resource/sign_out
      def destroy
        super
      end

      # protected

      # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the   sanitizer.
      def configure_sign_in_params
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
      end
    end
```

But this causes an ActionController::UnknownFormat Exception at `super` in the `create` block.

What's the best way to make Devise play nicely in this situation without needed to rename our existing models?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by editing the `url` param given to `form_with` in Devise view.

First run `rails generate devise:views` to copy Devise views to your project if you haven't.

Then open `app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` and change the first line from

```rb
<%= form_with(model: resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

to

```rb
<%= form_with(model: resource, as: resource_name, url: new_user_session_path) do |f| %>
```

That way, Devise won't try to use your session routes instead of its own.

Comment: Thank you! I had an existing session record and this helped me get the login functionality working again.